# In clojure, how to merge several maps combining mappings with same key into a list?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, I would like to combine several maps into a single map where mappings with same key are combined into a list.

For example:

```
{:humor :happy} {:humor :sad} {:humor :happy} {:weather :sunny}
```

should lead to:

```
{:weather :sunny, :humor (:happy :sad :happy)}
```

I thought about:

```
(merge-with (comp flatten list) data)
```

But it is not efficient because flatten has **O(n)** complexity.

Then I came up with:

```
(defn agg[x y] (if (coll? x) (cons y x) (list y x)))
(merge-with agg data)
```

But it feels not **idiomatic**. Any other idea?

Comment: last one also causes problems of your map values include collections....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One approach would be

```
(defn merge-lists [& maps]
  (reduce (fn [m1 m2]
            (reduce (fn [m [k v]]
                      (update-in m [k] (fnil conj []) v))
                    m1, m2))
          {}
          maps))
```

It's a bit ugly, but that's only because your values aren't already lists. It also forces *everything* to be a list (so you'd get `:weather [:sunny]` rather than `:weather :sunny`). Frankly, this is likely to be a million times easier for you to work with anyway.

If you had each value as a vector already, you could simply do `(apply merge-with into maps)`. So, another thing you could try would be to convert to vectors first, and then do the simple `merge-with`. This probably performs a bit worse than the first approach because of the intermediate data structures.

```
(defn merge-lists [& maps]
  (apply merge-with into
         (for [m maps, [k v] m]
           {k [v]})))
```

Comment: I would have expected that `(apply merge-with (fnil conj []) {} data)` would work, but unfortunately it doesn't. :(

Comment: What do you mean by 'If you had each value as a vector already'? Please write the exact definition of `maps`.

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit If your input maps were `{:humor (:happy)} {:humor (:sad) }` instead of `{:humor :happy} {:humor :sad}` then `merge-with into` would work on them.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following, I think it's pretty efficient

```
(reduce 
  (fn [m pair] (let [[[k v]] (seq pair)]
                 (assoc m k (cons v (m k))))) 
  {} 
  data)

=> {:weather (:sunny), :humor (:happy :sad :happy)}
```

Comment: This only works if each map has exactly one k/v pair, which wasn't the impression I got of the goal (since he said maps).

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, though, you can skip the `let`, by instead doing `(fn [m [[k v]]] ...)`.

Comment: @amalloy I tried that but I couldn't get it to work without the let: "nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap". Could be a destructuring bug somewhere in 1.3?

Comment: No, you're quite right. I made an assertion without thinking about it or trying it; I forgot maps don't like to be destructured, so this transformation that looks reasonable for pairs doesn't work for maps.

Answer (score 2):

@amalloy's answer can flattened a little bit by using `for`.

```
(reduce (fn [m [k v]] (update-in m [k] (fnil conj []) v)) {} (for [m data entry m] entry))
```

Source for this technique: http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2010/01/19/clojure-refactoring-flattening-reduces/

Answer (score 1):

Merge with this function:

```
(defn acc-list [x y]
  (let [xs (if (seq? x) x (cons x nil))]
    (cons y xs)))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using group-by? It doesn't return exactly what you ask for but it is very similar:

```
user=> (group-by first (concat {:humor :happy} {:humor :sad} {:humor :happy} {:weather :sunny :humor :whooot}))
{:humor [[:humor :happy] [:humor :sad] [:humor :happy] [:humor :whooot]], :weather [[:weather :sunny]]}
```

Or with a small modification to the group-by function:

```
(defn group-by-v2
 [f vf coll]
  (persistent!
    (reduce
     (fn [ret x]
       (let [k (f x)]
         (assoc! ret k (conj (get ret k []) (vf x)))))
     (transient {}) coll)))
```

becomes:

```
user=> (group-by-v2 key val (concat {:humor :happy} {:humor :sad} {:humor :happy} {:weather :sunny :humor :whooot}))
{:humor [:happy :sad :happy :whooot], :weather [:sunny]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution where every value is represented as lists, even if singletons:

```
(->> [{:humor :happy} {:humor :sad} {:humor :happy} {:weather :sunny}]
     (map first)
     (reduce (fn [m [k v]] (update-in m [k] #(cons v %))) {}))

=> {:weather (:sunny), :humor (:happy :sad :happy)}
```

If you don't want to wrap singletons in a list then I thought your original solution was just fine. The only way to make it more idiomatic is to use core.match.

```
(->> [{:humor :happy} {:humor :sad} {:humor :happy} {:weather :sunny}]
     (apply merge-with #(match %1
                               [& _] (conj %1 %2)
                               :else [%1 %2])))

=> {:weather :sunny, :humor [:happy :sad :happy]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same amount of keys in your collection:

```
(defn fn-format [maps]
  (reduce (fn [r k] ; result = {}, keys = [:humor, :weather]
           (assoc r k (mapv #(get % k) maps)))
           {}
           [:humor, :weather]))

(fn-format [{:humor :happy :weather :cloudy}
            {:humor :sad :weather :sunny}
            {:humor :happy :weather :rainy}
            {:weather :sunny :humor :happy}])

=> {:humor [:happy :sad :happy :happy], :weather [:cloudy :sunny :rainy :sunny]}
```