# Convert map of list into list of maps (i.e. rows to colums)

Tags: list, clojure, maps, transformation

I have the following data structure in Clojure

```
{:a [1 2 3]
 :b [4 5 6]
 :c [7 8 9]}
```

And I'd like to convert it into something like

```
[{:a 1 :b 4 :c 7}
 {:a 2 :b 5 :c 8}
 {:a 3 :b 6 :c 9}]
```

At the moment I'm kinda stumped as to how to do this.

Comment: For the inverse see a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408846/in-clojure-how-to-merge-several-maps-combining-mappings-with-same-key-into-a-li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
(defn transpose-lists [x] 
  (map (fn [m] (zipmap (keys x) m)) (apply map vector (vals x))))
```

Unfortunately it doesn't preserve order of the keys.
If anyone has a better solution then of course I'd like to hear it!

Comment: There is no concept or "ordering" of keys in a hash map

Comment: Totally forgot about that. I was thrown off by the different ordering of the elements in the prints from the REPL I guess!

Comment: This code assumes that 'keys' and 'vals' return entries in the same order. Even if it happens to work I don't think their contracts guarantee that.

Comment: @dimagog That is guaranteed.

Comment: None exists, which is a bit of a hole in my claim. Rich Hickey, who must be considered the authoritative source, has said that this is guaranteed, but apparently refuses to document it.

Comment: @dimagog: I guess `vals` will first use `keys` and then for each key return val from the map and hence it would make it same order as keys

Comment: @amalloy If you have commit access to Clojure repo please consider adding this to the doc strings for both fns.

Comment: @Ankur An efficient implementation for 'vals' certainly won't do that.

Comment: The only person with commit access to the Clojure repo is Rich Hickey. Feel free to submit a patch to fix the issue yourself; I find the entire jira process too frustrating to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

In Clojure you can never guarantee the order of keys in maps after transformations. They're indexed by key, not by order.

Vectors are, however. And with `get-in` you can do a lookup on position with a vector of coordinates .

```
=> (def mat
     [[1 2 3]
      [4 5 6]
      [7 8 9]])

=> (defn transpose
     [m]
     (apply mapv vector m))

=> (get-in (transpose mat) [1 2])
8
```