# Merge maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have two maps of the following structure:

```
(def a {:key1 10, :key2 100})
(def b {:key1 50, :key3 10})
```

I want an output of the form:

```
{:key1 {:val1 10, :val2 50}, 
 :key2 {:val1 100, :val2 nil}, 
 :key3 {:val1 nil, :val2: 10}}
```

I looked at `merge-with` but that only applies a function when a key exists in both the maps. The other solution was to make a set of keys from both the maps and then reduce over it to make the structure that I want, but that does not feel very "idiomatic" Clojure.

Comment: This is an almost duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408846/in-clojure-how-to-merge-several-maps-combining-mappings-with-same-key-into-a-li?rq=1.

Comment: I checked that question before posting, but it was different from what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn my-merge [labeled-maps] 
    (->> (for [[label m] labeled-maps
               [k v] m]
           {k {label v}})
         (apply merge-with merge)))
```

---

```
(def merged (my-merge {:val1 a, :val2 b}))

merged
;=> {:key3 {:val2 10}, :key1 {:val2 50, :val1 10}, :key2 {:val1 100}}
```

---

You don't need or want explicit nils introduced when a key is missing. That would make a legitimate `nil` value from the source maps indistinguishable from a `nil` introduced by the merge.

```
(get-in [:key3 :val1] merged)
;=> nil (either no value for :key3 in the map labeled :val1 or the value was nil)

(get-in [:key3 :val1] merged ::not-found)
;=> :user/not-found (this is clear here since we did not introduce any new nils)
```